# Can react-native be used with Java and Tomcat, without node?

Tags: react-native

My team is familiar with Java and we don't have much time to learn "nodejs" and the related "express" framework.  We really want to use `react-native` to develop some application.

I'm frustrated, since I don't know whether I can use react-native with Java and an Apache Tomcat Backend.

If it is possible, what should I do to make it work?

If not, how do make it possible? By using node as the request dispatcher?

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can! React Native is a backend-agnostic technology. Just write your backend in any way you want and expose an API that can be consumed by your application!

For communication with your backend you can use "fetch", "websocket" or "xmlhttprequest". You can find more information and examples in the official documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html

Comment: thank you ,i have never made an android app before ,maybe android has some api to request something ,or react-native has export some api for this

Comment: I've added some info about react-native API for backend communication. Hope that would be helpful for you.

Comment: ohthank you very much,
 that is exactly what i want !